# Cordova file reader don't work

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have a strange problem with the File Plugin in Cordova. The following code works fine if I run it as windows phone 8.1 app. But it fails if I run it as Windows Phone Universal App

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
       function (fs) {
           fs.root.getFile("www/test.xml", null, function (fileEntry) {
               fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
           }, fail);
       }, fail);
```

After the call of

```
function (fs) {
           fs.root.getFile("www/test.xml", null, function (fileEntry) {
               fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
           }, fail);
```

The Error Callback function is called with error code 1. This means, that the file isn't found. Does anyone have an idea whats the problem? And if so, how can I solve it.

I think, that I am in the wrong filesystem. Does anyone know which I have to use?

I know that there are some similiar questions, but they refer only to windows phone 8.1 and not to windows phone universal.
And I am using cordova in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it work as windows phone 8.1 app either.

I tried it with `{create:true}` using following codes:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function (fs) {
       fs.root.getFile("test.xml", { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
           fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
       }, fail);
}, fail);
```

and I got the `fileEntry` like below:
[image]

As you can see the `nativeURL` of the newly created file is `ms-appdata:///local//test.xml`,which means it was not created under application directory, but under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<application identity name>\LocalState` like below:

[image]

I researched the documentation but didn't find a way to retrieve the applicaiton directory files.
**So currently the workaround is to use windows API to get the file under application directory like below:**

```
if (cordova.platformId == "windows")
{
    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///www/test.xml");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).then(function (fs) {
                var abc = fs;//get the file here
             },fail);
 }
```